# backing up database with cron job in Ubuntu and parallel plesk

Tags: php, cron

I am using a php script to backup my database. Below is the given script:

```
$datestamp = date("Y-m-d_h-i-s");     // Current date to append to filename of backup file in format of YYYY-MM-DD

/* CONFIGURE THE FOLLOWING FOUR VARIABLES TO MATCH YOUR SETUP */
$dbuser = "xyz";     // Database username
$dbpwd = "*****";     // Database password
$dbname = "mydatabase";     // Database name. Use --all-databases if you have more than one
$filename = "backup-$datestamp.sql.gz";     // The name (and optionally path) of the dump file

$command = "mysqldump -u $dbuser --password=$dbpwd $dbname | gzip > $filename";
$result = system($command);
```

Below is the command line

```
php5  /var/www/vhosts/cc.astra1641.startdedicated.de/httpdocs/cron/backup.php
```

I have output the $result variable using var_dump to check it returns empty string. also I have tried using other methods like exec($command)  or passthru($command), it doesn't work.

Comment: Check the command's return value: `$result = system($command, $return); var_dump($return)`. never ignore return/diagnostic data, especially when things aren't working. ignoring it is like stuffing your fingers into your ears and going "lalalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: as i have mentioned it is returning NULL or empty string i have checked that already

Comment: $result is null, or $return?

Comment: i have solved the problem :) any how the problem was it was executing was creating dump on root level directory and i was searching for it on other directory thanks any ways :)